# Advance python code gives wrong output

Tags: python

The variable **cubes_by_four** should consist of the cubes of the numbers 1 through 10 only if the cube is evenly divisible by four.
I tried-

```
cubes_by_four = [i for i in range(1,10) if (i**3)%4 == 0]
print cubes_by_four
```

My output is-

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Problem is- **Oops, try again. Looks like cubes_by_four is the wrong length. It should have 5 values.**

Online tutorials learning site codeacademy.com  give me the error..
Where should i made the mistakes? Please Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `range(1,10)` will return the numbers 1-9. You need `range(1,11)` to get the numbers 1-10. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) for full details, but put simply:

`range(start, stop, step)` will return a list `[start, start + step, start + 2*step, ...]` where the final element will be *less than* stop (assuming that `step` is positive, if it's negative then it's *greater than* stop).

Your list comp then becomes

```
cubes_by_four = [i for i in range(1,11) if (i**3)%4 == 0]
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty easy to see that, if the cube of an integer is evenly divisible by 4, then the number must have 2 as a factor. So,

```
cubes = [i**3 for i in range(2, 11, 2)]
```